# sigabrt error during segue using present modally

Tags: ios, swift, segue

when i run my app the signup process works and creates a user in firebase
but then appears a sigabrt error when going the tab bar controller use present modally to preform the segue and there is no description for the error its blank.

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class signupViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signup: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cancel: UIButton!

var databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    password.secureTextEntry = true
  //  signup.enabled = true
}

@IBAction func didtapcancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func signuptaped(sender: AnyObject) {

   //     signup.enabled=true
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: {(user,error) in

            if error != nil {
                if error!.code == 17999 {

                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "error 17999", message: "ohh", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)

                }
            }

            else
            {
                FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(self.email.text!, password: self.password.text!, completion: {(user,error) in

                    if (error == nil) {

                        self.databaseref.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("email").setValue(self.email.text!)
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("tabbar", sender: sender)

                       // let alert = UIAlertController(title: "error ", message: "tt", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        //alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                      //  self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
            }


            }
        )}

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You have tried to present view controller from your tab bar controller? Right?

Comment: i tried to present view controller after signing the user up by present modally from signup controller to the tab bar controller

Comment: what do you think @Mannopson